# removing Italian cypress

Tags: tree-removal

My backyard has about ten Italian cypress trees which are 25 feet tall. I plan to cut them down but my backyard does not have an enough space to make the entire trees fall down. So, the trees should be cut piece by piece from the top, I believe.

The thing is that I do not want to climb up a ladder for 25 feet. I would feel comfortable to climb up for 10~15 feet but no more than that. So, one plan I am thinking is to cut the top part of the trunk with a pole saw to lower the height of the tree to about 15~20 feet, standing on the ladder. Then, the rest trunk would be cut with a normal chain saw. The top trunk seems to be thin but I am not sure if the pole saw would have enough power to cut the trunk.

I am just wondering if this plan makes sense. If the only choice is for me to go up to the top of the tree, I would probably hire a professional.

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't have enough room to fell the tree and you don't have the right equipment then this is job for an arborist.

Comment: [here you go...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JkFpJ.gif) Well.. Not really.

Comment: Hire an arborist. He should have insurance that covers all potential damage, you most likely don't. And *ten* trees is no picknick. Besides, climbing a ladder, wielding a pole saw is a disaster waiting to happen, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would then probably hire an arborist.

Answer (score 1):

**Hire an arborist**

And this is coming from someone who prunes all his own trees.

Felling trees is not as easy as it looks.  With the space considerations and the fact that there are ten of them, you really are going to want a professional.

Also, Stephie brings up a great point in her comment, a professional has insurance.  There are a myriad of things that can go wrong, and he is covered, and has the experience and proper equipment.